# How do I make batch files to handle certian commands

Tags: batch-file, dos

I need help making a batch file in ms dos to do certain commands like:

1. Request from you to first press any key
2. List the contents of the C:\WINDOWS directory
3. Create a subdirectory on one of your local drives. Use your initials to name the subdirectory.
4. Copy all the text files from C:\WINDOWS directory into the new subdirectory.
5. Print one of the text files copied to your new subdirectory.

for 5. I think I need to make a call to a command to print

Comment: You have already asked the same question

Comment: You're persistent... I'll give you that. You've already asked this question, been told to actually ask an answerable question and had your question closed.

Comment: I wish StackOverflow was around when I was in school/college.

Comment: dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1227237/batch-file or vice versa

Comment: @dave s: I deleted the original of this question that had gotten so many downvotes before you added details to make the question answerable.

Answer (score 5):

You need to create a .bat file that has the following text:

a)Request from you to first press any key

```
pause
```

b) List the contents of the C:\WINDOWS directory

```
dir c:\windows
```

c) Create a subdirectory on one of your local drives. Use your initials to name the subdirectory.

```
md c:\ro
```

d) Copy all the text files from C:\WINDOWS directory into the new subdirectory.

```
copy c:\windows\*.txt c:\ro
```

Regarding printing files I'm not sure, if I remember correctly the simplest way is something like:

```
type file.txt > LPT1
```

To create a .bat file, you should type in:

```
copy con filename.bat
... print the relevant lines above
```

When finished press Ctrl-Z and Enter.

So, all in all, you should type in:

```
copy con filename.bat
pause
dir c:\windows
md c:\ro
copy c:\windows\*.txt c:\ro
type file.txt > LPT1
```

And then Ctrl-Z and Enter.

Update: If you don't want the commands to be printed to the user, you can add another line before `pause` that will contain `@echo off`.

Answer (score 2):

Check out Rob van der Woude's Scripting Pages, specifically the [Batch Files](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/batchfiles.php) section.  He has an excellent reference with lots of tips and tricks that will help with most of these tasks.

Answer (score 1):

Command line help is your friend here for most of this.  You will need to have input parameters specified for a number of the things you;re asking for, though.

As a quick search, [try this article.](http://www.computerhope.com/batch.htm)